# ExtJS 4.2.1 , Tree, adding children to a node

Tags: javascript, extjs, tree, append, treenode

I am working with ExtJS 4.2.1

I am trying to append children to a leaf when I click on it.
It initially is a leaf, the click transform it into a folder and I would like to append leaves as children to this node.

It worked in Ext 3.4 but it seems there is a problem with the `appendChild()` method in 4.2.1. I get an  `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'updateInfo'` from this method due to `node.updateInfo(commit);` that we can find in `appendChild()`.

This is a pretty simple instruction:

In Ext3

```
    node.leaf = false; 
        // add nodes in trees
        for  ( i =0 ; i < timesheetData.length ; i++ ) 
        {
            // we create a new node and state it's a timesheet 
            var newNode =  new Ext.tree.TreeNode({
                 id : timesheetData[i].id, 
                 text : timesheetData[i].text, 
                 ts : true }) ;
            node.appendChild(newNode);

        } 
    node.expand();
```

In Ext4

```
    node.set('leaf', false); 
        // add nodes in trees
        for  ( i =0 ; i < timesheetData.length ; i++ ) 
        {

            node.appendChild({
                 id : timesheetData[i].id, 
                 text : timesheetData[i].text, 
                 ts : true });

        } 
    node.expand();
```

`Ext.tree.TreeNode` doesn't exist anymore in 4.2.1. 
So I try to append the child directly. But it doesn't work!

What could I do?

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Try this in your tree listener:

```
itemclick: function( record, item, index, e, eOpts ){
            item.appendChild({
                text: 'Hi! I am a leaf',
                leaf: true
            });
           }
```